# c++ warning: ‘t’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized] cm(t,n);

Tags: c++, linux, google-colaboratory

Compilation séparée

I get the probleme why doesn't work

```
!g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -c cm1.cpp -o cm1.o

cm1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
cm1.cpp:14:5: warning: ‘t’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   cm(t,n);
   ~~^~~~~
```

---

Compilation all the part to test

```
!g++ cm1.o cm.o -o test
```

---

### execute

### here when i use just g++ cm1.cpp -o cm1.o

```
!./test 4
```

4: argument pair

---

```
!./test 4 4
```

Syntaxe: ./test (n impair)

---

but when i try the right number give me nothing

```
!./test 5
```

---

the parte of code is:

### --
1st

```
%%writefile cm.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
void cm(int **t,int n);
```

---

### 2nd

```
%%writefile cm.cpp
#include "cm.hpp"

void cm(int **t,int n){
  
  int l, c, exl, exc;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) t[i][j] = 0;

  l = 0; c = n/2; t[l][c] = 1; 

  for(int i = 2; i <= n*n; i++) { 
    exl = l; exc = c;
    l--; if(l < 0) l = n-1;
    c++; if(c > n-1) c = 0;
    if(t[l][c] != 0) { l = exl+1; c = exc; }
    t[l][c] = i;
  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
      cout << setw(6) << t[i][j];
    cout << endl;
  }
  unsigned trace = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) trace += t[i][i];   
  cout << "Somme magique = trace: " << trace << endl;
}
```

---

part 3

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
if(argc != 2) {
  cout << "Syntaxe: " << argv[0] << " <n impair>" << endl; 
  exit(1);  
}   
int n;
n= atoi(argv[1]);
if(n % 2 == 0) {
cout << n << ": argument pair\n"; 
exit(2);    
}  int **t1;

cm(t1,n);

return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Your posted code doesn't have `cm(t,n);`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). `t1` in `cm(t1,n);` isn't initialized and will cause trouble anyway.

Comment: similar comment as to your previous question: Pointers are not arrays. You have `int** t1` pass that to `cm` and then suddenly you pretend that there is a 2d array by writing `t[i][j] = 0;`

Comment: did you already consider to use `std::vector` ? vectors can be passed to and returned from functions like anything else, arrays not.

Comment: get the same probleme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize `t1` by allocating buffers before passing it to the function.

```
}  int **t1;

// allocate an array of pointers
t1 = new int*[n];
// allocate arrays for each row
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  t1[i] = new int[n];
}

cm(t1,n);
```